# git error (caused by local commit)

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I used git to checkout code from central repository. After I changed the code, I cannot make commits to that central repository, so I made commit to local repository.

Now without affecting the central repository, can I make my changes available at other place?
I mean: How to convey my local changes to other places?

The need for this arises as follows: Since central repo is public and not our own, we locally use cvs to maintain versioning. So, after making local git commit, it is producing error at other place, as follows:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Thanks. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has a clone function which will allow you to do this. Just google "git clone"

Comment: Thanks. Never knew about that! The only thing I need now is: How to clone when I need to do that across two computers. I mean 1. developing on one computer 2. Making a clone on another computer (both are connected to internet). I should be able to sometimes make changes in one and commit and pull in another.

Comment: Yes, what you can do is put a git repository in a centralized location (ie. a server) clone that repository on as many machines as you like, you will commit your changes locally and when you are ready to put the changes on the main repository you can use a git push command. Here's a link of how it is done at sourceforge.[sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git) Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I want to set it up on our own servers, instead of sourceforge. I tried using http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/create-a-new-git-remote-repository-from-some-local-files-or-local-git-repository/ but it fails, since my repo is already a git branch. Also my collaborators also have to work on this project.

Comment: I know you didn't want to use sourceforge, I was just using that as an example, sorry for the confusion. I don't know how far you are into your project, but have you tried deleting the existing git repo in your project (it's a hidden folder labeled .git), and then just creating a new one like in the link you provided? I don't know if that is a viable solution in your case, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the location which `remote` points to, then a commit to the "central repository"  would go there instead.

As @ReidMac said, you can `git clone` your local repository, but any future commits would not be transferred automatically.

Basically, the only way to have your commits go somewhere else involves changing the `remote` locations specified in head.

Comment: My repo is already a git. Can you suggest a way to 1. Now make a new repository on a server 2. Make my folder track that 3. The repository on the server will allow others also to clone and develop their work. We were using cvs earlier but that git and cvs together don't work.

Comment: Set up the new repository the exact same way you set up your local one - `git init, etc...` - then you can `git push/pull` to that repo, and add others to the repository granting them access to push/pull. Google is your friend.

Comment: I tried a lot with google and stack-overflow answers, but could not set-up. Would you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to go into the `HEAD` file and change where `remote` is set to push to. Other than that I've got nothing, sorry.